# Is there a way to specify a default install folder for Visual Studio Extensions?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to save my SSD from to much thrashing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Q: Is there a way to specify a default install folder for Visual Studio Extensions?
A: No.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, worrying about that *definitely* distracts from the joy of spending the money.  It makes no sense, it only thrashes when it is *written* frequently.  The install folder for an extension only gets written to once.